# How to put a condition while using a GroupBy in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have used the following code to make a distplot.

```
data_agg = data.groupby('HourOfDay')['travel_time'].aggregate(np.median).reset_index()

plt.figure(figsize=(12,3))
sns.pointplot(data.HourOfDay.values, data.travel_time.values)
plt.show()
```

However I want to choose hours above 8 only and not 0-7. How do I proceed with that?

Comment: Use `data[data['HourOfDay'] > 7]` before your solution

Comment: What is the format of the column `HourOfDay`

Answer (score 0):

What about filtering first?

```
data_filtered = data[data['HourOfDay'] > 7]
# depending of the type of the column of date 
data_agg = data_filtered.groupby('HourOfDay')['travel_time'].aggregate(np.median).reset_index() 
plt.figure(figsize=(12,3))
Sns.pointplot(data_filtered.HourOfDay.values, data_filtered.travel_time.values) 
plt.show()
```